# How to git checkout a version of code from before my clone?

Tags: git, git-checkout

How can I checkout a version of code from before I cloned it? Usually I would do `git reflog` to get the version number and then do a `git checkout 'version number'`, but if I've cloned after the commit was made that I want, it doesn't show up as an option in `git reflog`. Is there still a way to go back to this commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clone a Git repo, you usually bring in the entire history.  So, if you want to checkout a version earlier than the HEAD, you may try using `git log` (not `git reflog`).  Then, find the commit you want to checkout, and just use `git checkout <SHA-1>` as you already suggested.